# Hiding some items in student's handout using beamer

Tags: beamer

I am creating a presentation and along with the presentation (that I am going to show in the class), I am trying to make a student handout. So far, everything is fine. The part I am struggling with is that I would like to hide some parts of the presentation in the handout. Then students are supposed to write down these parts in their handouts during the presentation. One way I can do this (suggested by a friend!) is by changing the color of the "to be hidden" part. Is there any other more systematic way of doing it?

---

On a simple example it works. But in my document I got into trouble. The only difference between my code and yours is in Preamble. I use

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}     
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
```

In my code and for `handout`, I comment the first line and specifically `\item<beamer>` doesn't work at all. I am using a lot of different packages. I was wondering if any package possibly can create problem. By the way `\only<beamer> { ... }` works fine and I only have trouble with `\item<beamer>`

UPDATE: I found the problem! It had problem with `\setbeamercovered{transparent=50}` after making this line a comment, it worked well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might depend on how you are producing the handout; if you are using the `handout` class option, then you can use the `beamer` mode specification for the material that you want only for the presentation and not for the handout. A little example: processing the following simple document as it is:

```
\documentclass%[handout]%
{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First test frame}
\only<beamer>{Text for the presentation.}
Text for presentation and handout
\begin{itemize}
\item Item for presentation and handout.
\item<beamer> Item for presentation.
\item Another item for presentation and handout.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<beamer>{Second test frame}
\only<beamer>{Another example text for the presentation.}
Text for presentation and handout
\begin{block}<beamer>{Example block}
Some text in the block
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

you get the full document for the presentation:

[image]

Now, to produce the handout you uncomment the relevant parts:

```
\documentclass[handout]%
{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First test frame}
\only<beamer>{Text for the presentation.}
Text for presentation and handout
\begin{itemize}
\item Item for presentation and handout.
\item<beamer> Item for presentation.
\item Another item for presentation and handout.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle<beamer>{Second test frame}
\only<beamer>{Another example text for the presentation.}
Text for presentation and handout
\begin{block}<beamer>{Example block}
Some text in the block
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and now you get a handout document not showing the parts written in `beamer` mode:

[image]