# Hiding some slides in student handouts in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am preparing lecture slides for a class.
I would like to hide some of the slides from the students.
As an example, I would like to be able to compile
`students.pdf` which has only student slides 1 and 2
(i.e., "teacher slide" is hidden);
but `teacher.pdf` which has all three slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 1}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Teacher slide}
secret stuff not to be shared with students
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 2}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How would I do this in beamer?
In a regular document, e.g., `article`,
I would use the `comment` environment.

I feel that the approach in [Conditionally hidden slides in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43555/conditionally-hidden-slides-in-beamer)
is overkill for my needs.

Comment: Highly related question: [Hiding some items in student's handout using beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/hiding-some-items-in-students-handout-using-beamer),
Gonzalo Medina has a great answer there that you can use as well. Test this: `\mode<beamer>{\begin{frame}{teacher slide} ... \end{frame}}` and compile with and without the `handout` option

Comment: You can also say e.g. `\onslide<3| handout:0>{Stuff for teacher slide.}` if you want just some slides within a frame included in the handout.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `handout` mode to produce the handout for students, as suggested in the comments, you can just specify the relevant bits as an argument passed to the `frame` environment. No need for an explicit `\mode` at all.

For example:

```
% \documentclass{beamer}% for teacher version
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}% for student version

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 1}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<1-| handout:0>{Teacher slide}
secret stuff not to be shared with students
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 2}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Student output:

[image: 2 frames]

Teacher output:

[image: 3 frames]

As I mentioned in comments, you can use this within a frame, too. Anywhere where you can pass an overlay specification, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is package [`multiaudience`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience). One can define several desired audiences

```
\SetNewAudience{teacher}
\SetNewAudience{students}
```

and filter which part of the document is desired for every audience group or groups.

```
\begin{shownto}{teacher}
...
\end{shownto}
```

Command `\DefCurrentAudience{students}` fixes desired audience before compilation, although it can also be fixed in compilation command

```
`pdlatex "\def\CurrentAudience{students}\input{your-tex-file}"`
```

A complet example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multiaudience}

% Declare all possible audience groups
\SetNewAudience{teacher}
\SetNewAudience{students}

\DefCurrentAudience{students}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 1}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\begin{shownto}{teacher}
\begin{frame}{Teacher slide}
secret stuff not to be shared with students
\end{frame}
\end{shownto}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 2}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result for students:

[image]

and teachers

[image]