# Short and long presentations in one beamer document

Tags: beamer

I look for a sensible way to keep different versions of the same talk in one beamer file: e.g., 15 min and 1 hour versions, where some content is common, but some is not. Is there a nice way to toggle between versions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\title{Presentation} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 1} % both 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the gist of it} % only short 
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the detailed version } % only long
%\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the detailed version, contd.} % only long
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 3} % both
\end{frame}

% etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another alternative to provided answers could be package `multiaudience` as is shown in [Hiding some slides in student handouts in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273781/1952)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can label each frame `\begin{frame}[label=both]`  and then use

```
\includeonlyframes{<frame label list>}
```

A sample:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\includeonlyframes{title,both,short1,both1}      %% for short
\includeonlyframes{title,both,long1,long2,both1}  %% for long
\begin{document}

\title{Presentation}
\begin{frame}[label=title]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=both]{Issue 1} % both
both
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=short1]{Issue 2 - the gist of it} % only short
short 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=long1]{Issue 2 - the detailed version } % only long
long 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=long2]{Issue 2 - the detailed version, contd.} % only long
long 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=both1]{Issue 3} % both
both 1
\end{frame}

% etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use just `long`, `short` and `both`?

Comment: @Adobe Certainly, *if* you can live with lots of warnings :)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `environ` package to create a new `lvframe` environment for frames that will appear in the "long version" of the presentation. The `frame` environment would be used for those in both. A boolean could then be used to switch between the two:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\iflongversion \longversiontrue%change to \longversiontrue to include the frames in the long version
\NewEnviron{lvframe}[3][]{%
    \iflongversion\begin{frame}[environment=lvframe,#1]{#2}{#3}
    \BODY
    \end{frame}\fi}

\begin{document}

\title{Presentation} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 1} % both 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the gist of it} % only short 
\end{frame}

\begin{lvframe}{Issue 2 - the detailed version }{} % only long
\end{lvframe}

\begin{lvframe}{Issue 2 - the detailed version, contd.}{} % only long
\end{lvframe}

\begin{frame}{Issue 3} % both
\end{frame}

% etc.

\end{document}
```

Change `\longversionfalse` to `\longversiontrue` to get the "long version".

**Edit:**

The above is the corrected answer based on the comments from the OP and @MickG below. This definition *should* handle the most common implementations of `\begin{frame}`, specifically those of the form `\begin{frame}[options]{title}{subtitle}`. Note that `{}` is required if the `subtitle` argument is not wanted (`lvframe` does not have the same complex optional argument parsing of `frame`). Also, this will not work if `<overlay>` is needed.

Comment: Very nice and tidy solution.

Comment: Nice approach. The literal solution just adds stuff, but I guess one can use same trick to create `svframe` for short-only material.

Comment: Also a minor point: frame title only work when given as `\frametitle{}` not as an argument to the frame environment.

Comment: Should the titles of `lvframe`s not be in `[]`s rather than `{}`s? I seem to see an empty default for that `#1`…

Comment: OP and @MickG: Excellent observations. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I manage it with `versions` package that lets me easily include/exclude possibly many contiguous frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{versions}
%
\newboolean{longversion}
%
% Uncomment the following line to get the long version
% \setboolean{longversion}{true}
%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{longversion}}{%
  \includeversion{longversion}
  \excludeversion{shortversion}
}{%
  \excludeversion{longversion}
  \includeversion{shortversion}
}
\begin{document}

\title{Presentation}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Issue 1} % both
\end{frame}

\begin{shortversion}
  \begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the gist of it} % only short
  \end{frame}
\end{shortversion}

\begin{longversion}
  \begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the detailed version } % only long
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Issue 2 - the detailed version, contd.} % only long
  \end{frame}
\end{longversion}

\begin{frame}{Issue 3} % both
\end{frame}

% etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: by far the most useful answer for me. thanks!

Comment: Also works inside frames to hide parts of it and with verbatim environments like listings package. Note: The `\begin` and `\end` don't have to be in the beginning of the line, like with the comment package.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package exactly for this purpose, the `beameraudience` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[
    audience=experts
%   audience=beginners  
]{beameraudience}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
 all version
\end{frame}

\justfor{beginners}{
    \begin{frame}{Title}
      long version
    \end{frame}
}

\justfor{experts}{
    \begin{frame}{Title}
      short version
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```