# Deactivating invisible in beamer in handout mode

Tags: beamer, handout

I am using the invisible option in my presentation, but I would like to also have a print version where the invisible option is activated. When I use the handout mode, only the first version of each slide is printed (that is, the items becoming visible later are not displayed). I don't want to manually remove all the invisible instances. Is there a method to deactivate all the invisible instances?

Thanks and here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[handout, english]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Questions:}
  \begin{itemize}
      \invisible<1>{\item[A.] Question 1.}
      \pause\invisible<-2>{\item[B.] Question 2.}
       \pause\invisible<-3>{\item[B.] Question 3.}
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Kurt May I notice that in the 2 answers to [Hiding some slides in student handouts in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273666/hiding-some-slides-in-student-handouts-in-beamer)  an entire frame is being hidden not some slides of the same frame. For me It is not the same thing and I think that the question  asked here is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help :

```
\documentclass[handout, english]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Questions:}
  \begin{itemize}
      \invisible<1|handout:0>{\item[A.] Question 1.}
      \pause\invisible<-2|handout:0>{\item[B.] Question 2.}
       \pause\invisible<-3|handout:0>{\item[B.] Question 3.}
       \pause
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @EvangelosCon Pleased to know that your problem has been solved!