# Replace text with underscores in Beamer handout

Tags: beamer, handout

I would like to create slides where some sections of texts are replaced by underscores (or an underline  of equivalent length)  in the student handouts.

I have seen [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/hiding-some-items-in-students-handout-using-beamer) but it only "blanks" the text. What I would like to do is replace it with underscores.

I have also seen [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266124) based on a customized `\hideit` command but I do not know how to replace the mbox by the appropriate number of underscores `_` characters.

ECM taken from the second link:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{itemize}
\item Example of itemize:
  \mode<handout>{%
  \item Some text _____________________ 
  }%
  \mode<beamer>{%
  \item Some text to be replaced by underscores
  }%
  \item This is visible in both handout and presentation.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See the `censor` package at, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125840/create-fill-in-the-blank-version-of-a-document-with-ability-to-toggle-blanks-on or this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165248/an-underline-with-texts-one-both-ends-of-a-line/165302#165302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace some text with the equivalent width of underscores, you could use `\underline{\phantom{some text}}`. The following command creates both versions:

```
\documentclass[%
handout
]{beamer} 

\newcommand{\hide}[1]{%
\only<handout>{\underline{\phantom{#1}}}%
\only<beamer>{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{itemize}
\item Example of itemize:
\item Some text to \hide{be replaced with underscores}
\item This is visible in both handout and presentation.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I haven't tested line returns, etc. But I'll make it involve. Thanks a lot!